# java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first [for a Table]

Tags: android, android-tablelayout, tablerow

I am drawing the `table` dynamically in my code. The `tablerow` I get from layout which I am just hardcoding in the XML. I don't know why I am getting this error and am completely out of ideas.

```
 TableRow tr = (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.tr);
        TableRow.LayoutParams rowParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    TextView textView1 = new TextView(this);
    textView1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    textView1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cell_shape);
    textView1.setText("1");
    textView1.setLayoutParams(rowParams);
    tr.addView(textView1);

    TextView textView2 = new TextView(this);
    textView2.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    textView2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cell_shape);
    textView2.setText("2");
    textView2.setLayoutParams(rowParams);
    tr.addView(textView2);

    TextView textView3 = new TextView(this);
    textView3.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    textView3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cell_shape);
    textView3.setText("3");
    textView3.setLayoutParams(rowParams);
    tr.addView(textView3);

    TextView textView4 = new TextView(this);
    textView4.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    textView4.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cell_shape);
    textView4.setText("4");
    textView4.setLayoutParams(rowParams);
    tr.addView(textView4);

    TextView textView5 = new TextView(this);
    textView5.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    textView5.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cell_shape);
    textView5.setText("5");
    textView5.setLayoutParams(rowParams);
    tr.addView(textView5);

    TextView textView6 = new TextView(this);
    textView6.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    textView6.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cell_shape);
    textView6.setText("6");
    textView6.setLayoutParams(rowParams);
    tr.addView(textView6);

    TextView textView7 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
    TableRow.LayoutParams params = (TableRow.LayoutParams)textView7.getLayoutParams();
    params.span = 6;
    textView7.setLayoutParams(params);

    //tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    //next row
    TableRow trNew = (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.newline);
    TableRow.LayoutParams rowParams1 = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    TextView textView8 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.model);
    textView8.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    textView8.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cell_shape);
    textView8.setText("Check");
    trNew.addView(textView8);
```

The error is caused by: `trNew.addView(textView8);`

My error message is:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `trNew.addView(textView8);` if you want to use the TextView that you have created in `XML`. If you want to use the dynamically created TextView then replace

```
TextView textView8 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.model);
```

by

```
 TextView textView8 = new TextView(this);
```

Answer (score 5):

When you initialize `textView8` using

```
TextView textView8 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.model);
```

that means it is from the XML and probably already has a parent. That is why you are getting the `IllegalStateException`

Change it to

```
TextView textView8 = new TextView(this);
```

instead as you have done for all the other `TextView`